# Calculating number of elements in an array in C sizeof(a)/sizeof(a+1)?

Tags: c

```
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    printf("%d",sizeof(a)/sizeof(a+1));
```

output:
        4

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Correct code would be sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]). This method is kind of hokey though.

Comment: Do you mean `int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's wrong.  `sizeof(a)` is the size of the array, and `sizeof(a+1)` is the size of a pointer.  Dividing the two makes no sense.

What the author probably intended is:

`sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`

Which will yield the number of elements in the array.  `sizeof a[0]` is the size of an `int`.

The reason your code gives you the right answer is because your machine happens to have `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`.

Aside:  Use `%zu` to print a `size_t`.

Comment: Technically the OP's program says `int a = …` so `a` is an `int` .

Comment: if we implement the sizeof operator then it gives 1

Comment: @PascalCuoq - that was a typo, clearly, and it's since been fixed.

Comment: @mahesh, what do you mean 'implement the sizeof operator'?

Comment: RE: Aside: [Apparently MS Visual C++ doesn't have `z`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6(v=vs.110).aspx), stating, "The hh, j, z and t length prefixes are unsupported." It instead requires the use of a different prefix: `I` (uppercase i, not lowercase L). In other words, if you want to do any C/C++ coding that will be cross platform, *don't* use Visual C++! There are other Windows compilers (mingw-w64 surfaces first in my mind, but there are others).

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, that sounds right.  Microsoft doesn't want to support C99 (or newer).

Comment: @Carl Norum: That may be true, but isn't it also a part of ISO C++? I haven't a copy or draft of the C++ standard at all handy, but I'm reasonably certain the implementation intentionally disregards parts of C++03 by not supporting those prefixes when the compiler obviously could. Why `%Iu` and `%Id` for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` types when `%zu` and `%zd` are standard? The same is true for hh, j and t as well. Hopefully MS fixes things sometime within the next 10 years or so when code like this fails too often.

Comment: That could very well be.  I don't know anything about C++, really.

Comment: @CarlNorum         sizeof(type) = (char *)(&type + 1) - (char *)(&type)